# How to add button in new layer at the left below fragment

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I am trying to add the red button (`android:id="@+id/button8`) under fragment in a new layer at the left position but it can't respond and still in the top as photo:

[image]

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="bottom"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/topLayout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ttt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#FF0000" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the RelativeLayout does not take in to consideration the order in which you put your elements in your xml. For that use a `LinearLayout`. In your case you have to specify that your layout is after the frament.

Try this :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ttt"
    android:layout_below="@id/topLayout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ttt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: see the corrected version. `layout_below` not `below`

Comment: I try the corrected code but the button disappear and I can,t see where its position

Comment: use `android:layout_above="@+id/ttt"` on your fragment and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` but without the below part as in my answer.